# How to automatically route to a child route in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an albums module that's loaded by the main app-router module. When clicking the `albums` link in the navigation, it directs to the `albums` module which loads an empty path and some child routes. The reason for this is the component assigned to the empty path has it's own navigation and router outlet. This component is the `AlbumContainer`.

The module has some child routes too. However, when I click on `albums` in the main navigation, I want it to automatically route to one of the children components / routes (`dates`). I know it's possible to just add the child route url to the main album navigation anchor, but then that prevents the main navigations `routerLinkActive` from functioning.

Is it possible that when I land on this module / component, that it automatically routes to the `dates` path?

In all other instances (in the albums sub menu), I'll be linking directly to the child route via the sub menu.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AlbumContainer,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dates',
        loadChildren: () => import('./dates/dates.module').then((mod) => DatesModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'artists',
        loadChildren: () => import('./art/profile.module').then((mod) => mod.ArtistsModule)
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

**HTML for reference**

```
<div>

  <!-- Sub Menu -->
  <div>
     <albums-menu></albums-menu>
  </div>

  <!-- Router Content -->
  <div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you want a automatic redirect to `/dates` route if there `/albums` present in the URL?

Comment: Hi Pankaj! - If it's just `albums` yes. But there are child routes which would have `/albums/artists/` and a few others too, so I wouldn't want those hindered if that makes sense?

Comment: add a child route with a `{path: '', redirectTo: 'dates' pathMatch: 'full'}` this will automatically make your router select the dates child if the route is otherwise empty.

Comment: Hey Mikel, would you mind writing an answer for that please as it works a treat! - I tried this but not as the child, it didn't occur to me to do it as a child route. Nice one!

Comment: Although, I've just noticed it work with params in the route. I'll figure something out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Redirect route to child routes

The angular router will try to match the route as a Tree, this means you can use `redirectTo` relative to the current position in the UrlTree by implementing it as a member of a set of child routes.

### Setup

**child route container**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-outlet',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})
export class OutletComponent {}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**child.component**

Simple dummy component that just joins the URL of the current path and shows it in its template:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `{{routeInfo}}`,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  routeInfo: string = '';
  constructor(private r: ActivatedRoute) {
    r.url.subscribe((url) => {
      this.routeInfo = url.join(" ");
    });
  }
}
```

### Routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OutletComponent,
    children: [{
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'childB',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: 'childB',
      component: ChildComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'childA',
      component: ChildComponent
    }]
  }
];
```

Angular will begin matching from the root of the UrlTree. In this instance, if we're at the root, it will check the children.

The trick here, is that inside the child routes, we've also defined an empty route with a redirect, but *because it is a child route, it will check if the route is empty, relative to its parent route, if pathMatch is set to full*

So, in this example, we will automatically be redirected to `/childB` if we do not currently have any route selected.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ygiwtn?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: But how to redirect to a dynamic child route ':id'?